# Sending mail with attachments and html data using nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

The problem I ran into is that I can only send an email with attachments OR template data, but I haven't found a way to send both.

Here's my code:

```
var EmailTemplate = require('email-templates').EmailTemplate;
var template = new EmailTemplate('templates/welcome');
template.render({}, function(err, results) {
  var send = transporter.templateSender({
    from: '<ouremail@gmail.com>',
    html: results.html,
    attachments: [{
      filename: 'file1.png',
      path: 'templates/file1.png',
      cid: 'file1'
    }, {
      filename: 'file2.png',
      path: 'templates/file2.png',
      cid: 'file2'
    }]
  });

  send({
    to: String(user.emailAddress),
    subject: 'Welcome to the Our Site!'
  }, {name: user.firstName}, callback);
});
```

If I do it the way shown above, the name template variable renders, but the pictures don't show up. If I instead do

```
var send = transporter.templateSender(template, ...
```

then the attachments render, and not the template variable.

I know that I could use a templating package like Jade or Handlebars for this kind of thing but that seems like overkill when nodemailer has all of the functionality I need.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was doing exactly same and I wasted my precious 4 hours to solve this just before Go LIVE.. But finally I found answer to this.

The place to keep attachments is in the `send()` part rather than `templateSender()`, so the code should look like this:

```
send({
    to: String(user.emailAddress),
    subject: 'Welcome to the Our Site!',
    attachments:[{
      filename: 'file1.png',
      path: 'templates/file1.png',
      cid: 'file1'
    }, {
      filename: 'file2.png',
      path: 'templates/file2.png',
      cid: 'file2'
    }]
  }, {name: user.firstName}, callback);
```

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: Thank you a million, this was really getting on my nerves. Now I can finally see the attached image. Just need to figure now how to actually embed it into an img tag from a Buffer and it's all done. Would you happen to know how to do that ?

Comment: @AdelaN, you can convert that buffer to base64 and and pass it on to the img tag

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. What eventually worked was having it the `src` with the content identifier, i.e. `<img src='cid:file1'/>`...